# PowerShell Deal with objects not in CSV

Tags: powershell

I'm new at PowerShell. I'm trying to create a script that will look through a CSV and through Active Directory Group. If the user is not in the CSV I want to remove the user(Currently using write-output for testing). I have to use UserPrincipalName. My CSV is just

Rank,Number

Something,3333 // This user is AD GROUP

Something,2222 // This user is NOT in AD GROUP

Currently, I want it to just output 3333, but it outputs both.

Import-Module activedirectory

$validUsers = Import-Csv 'C:\Users\Bang\Desktop\Bulk.csv' | Select-Object -Expand Number

$Users = Get-ADGroupMember 'Test' | %{Get-ADUser $_.SamAccountName | select UserPrincipalName}

foreach ($Member in $Users)

{

if ($Member -match $validUsers.Number){

Write-Output $Member}

}

Answer (score 2):

There's a few errors here.

```
$validUsers = Import-Csv 'C:\Users\Bang\Desktop\Bulk.csv' | Select-Object -Expand Number
```

Here you're expanding the `Number` column. That means `$validUsers` will be an array of strings, not an array of objects with a property named `Number`. Compare `Get-ChildItem C:\Windows | Select-Object -Property Name -First 5` to `Get-ChildItem C:\Windows | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name -First 5`.

```
$Users = Get-ADGroupMember 'Test' | %{Get-ADUser $_.SamAccountName | select UserPrincipalName}
```

Here, you didn't specify `-ExpandProperty`. That means the objects assigned to `$Users` will be an array of objects with a property named `UserPrincipalName`.

```
foreach ($Member in $Users)

{

if ($Member -match $validUsers.Number){

Write-Output $Member}

}
```

Here you're doing all kinds of stuff wrong. First, `$Member` is an element of `$Users`, which means it has the property `UserPrincipalName`. Second, `$validUsers` doesn't have any properties at all. It's just an array of unnamed strings. Third, `-match` is for matching a string with a regular expression. If you want to know if an element is in an array, you need to use the `-in` operator.

Try this:

```
$GroupName = 'Test'

$validUsers = Import-Csv 'C:\Users\Bang\Desktop\Bulk.csv' | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Number -Unique

$CurrentUsers = Get-ADGroupMember $GroupName | 
    Get-ADUser |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty UserPrincipalName -Unique

# Add valid users not already in the group
$validUsers | Where-Object { $_ -notin $CurrentUsers } |
    ForEach-Object { Get-AdUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName -eq '$_'" } |
    Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -MemberOf $GroupName -WhatIf

# Remove invalid users currently in the group    
$CurrentUsers | Where-Object { $_ -notin $validUsers } | 
    ForEach-Object { Get-AdUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName -eq '$_'" } |
    Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -MemberOf $GroupName -WhatIf
```

The `-WhatIf` parameters on `Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` and `Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` will cause those commands to just output what they're going to do instead of actually taking any actions. To actually run the script and update your group, you'll want to remove those parameters.

Edit: Unfortunately, most AD commands don't accept the user principal name as pipeline input. They wants distinguished name, SAM account name, SID, or GUID. The `ForEach-Object` is added in there to do the lookup again, which is a bit unfortunate.

This script could definitely be improved, but it should work for you now, based on what I think you're trying to do.

Comment: Thank you for this post. It is really insightful and has actually helped me to understand the various syntaxes used. However, one thing when adding users not already in the group, "UserPrincipalName -eq '$_'" The problem is, it can't be referenced because it's not an exact match. Which is why I was trying to find a way to find anything that contains the string or term.

Comment: I see. In that case I would try `"UserPrincipalName -like '*$_*'"`.